# Why one of this method works for Shring Image of ImageView?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview, drawable

This fist method is working fine but I am not able to save this image file to a cache. Like I want to save it temporarily.

```java
btnShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) ivMeme.getDrawable();
                Bitmap b = drawable.getBitmap();
                //Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.refer_pic);
                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("image/*");
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
                String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                        b, "MEME", "Just A MEME");
                Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(path);
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Shared via MemeSharing App");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share this Meme using"));
        }
        });
```

I am not able to convert this method to save file at `getExternalCacheDir()`
This second Method Just able to save file locally but not able to share that image file. As goes for share app goes down.

```java
btnShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) ivMeme.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

                File filepath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath()+"/Demo/");
                Log.d("Error:01",dir.getAbsolutePath());
                dir.mkdir();
                File file = new File(dir,System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");

                try {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"InSide Try ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.d("Error:1",e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,outputStream);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Saved Successfully "+file.getAbsolutePath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                try {
                    outputStream.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("Error:2",e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("Error:3",e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("image/*");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"Share via"));
          }
        });
```

I don't know why second method is not working? I have tried both method for sharing Image of ImageView, only one of them is working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: As it's get closed if I try to save file otherwise it run perfectly. So I think this is different then mentioned one.

Comment: `dir.mkdirs();` Bad coding. Better: `if(!dir.exists()) if(!dir.mkdirs()) return;` Also display a Toast() to inform the user. Please adapt your code and try again.

Comment: It is not showing any Toast, which I have added for `dir.mkdirs()`

Comment: So the conclusion was....? And you forget to return and stop.

Comment: `catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }` if there is a catch you should display a Toast to inform the user. And return/stop. Now you continue as if all went ok.

Comment: Atleast one them should popup...But this is not happening.
`if(!dir.exists()) {
            if(dir.mkdirs())
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Directory Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not able to create directory", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Directory already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }`
Either Directory exists or not any condition one of these Toast should popup..